# Replace/add class in header element

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm using a WP child theme and need to replace and/or add another class to the header tag via the functions.php to avoid editing the parent theme header.php.

The code is the usual stuff:

```
<header class="class1">
<!--bunch of divs-->
</header>
```

I need it to be:

```
<header class="class1 Class2">
```

The class1 is only used in this tag, if that helps.

I'm not a coder, so would appreciate a specific answer, since I'll be unable to recreate any solution no matter how many bits and hints you give me… sorry about it.

Comment: SO is not a place to “order” your very own copy&paste-ready solution. If you don’t know anything about coding – then either start to learn it, or _hire_ someone who does.

Comment: This is not a software factory...

Comment: Thank you for letting me know, it was not my intention to disrespect you all.

Answer (score 0):

moving header.php into your child theme is trivial. just do it. and edit accordingly. ps. doing it like you want is impossible. or super tricky like using js.

Comment: Thanks, yes, I've thought about it. I'm just trying to avoid issues when updating the parent theme.

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery to add or remove header or any element's class
'
    $( document ).ready(function() {
    $('header').addClass('classname');
    $('header').removeClass('classname');
    )};
'